# jquery - retrieving changes to a form

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am trying to retrieve the html of the "today_div" as it looks like in the browser.

Problem is that even if the user clicks on the checkbox, the html of the div does not show "checked" in the checkbox html when retrieving as below.

How can one retrieve the html with the changes?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="today_div">
<input type="checkbox" name="as" class="achk">
</div>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" defer=true>

$(document.body).on( "change",'.achk', function() {
    var s = $('#today_div').html();
    alert(s);
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: anyone know why the above does not work? if the user checked the checkbox that is not enough? he must also set it in javascript. very strange.

Comment: *"I am trying to retrieve the html of the "today_div" as it looks like in the browser."* - Can you explain why you would want to do that?

Comment: trying to store it and retrieve later.

Comment: did you try on mouseup ? otherwise me think it's about the javascript engine of the browser, attaching the check property to the javascript object, not updating html attr, in other words yuo have to update the html in your handler to take care of putting the check attr where it belongs

Comment: @Ray: That explains nothing. Store where? Retrieve for what? Besides: Storing HTML snippets as a sting is ill-advised and a code smell. There is no well-designed application that should ever need to do this.

Comment: @Tomalak I hear. good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on( "change",'.achk', function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
       $(this).attr("checked","checked");
    }else{
       $(this).removeAttr("checked");
    }
    var s = $('#today_div').html();

    alert(s);
});
```

see **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/6SQ5Z/2/)**

reference **[attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

Answer (score 2):

do like:

```
$(document.body).on( "change",'.achk', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        is_checked = $(this).attr("checked") ? "checked" : "";
    $this[0].setAttribute("checked", is_checked);
    alert($('#today_div').html());
});
```

Demo :: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M4Mn7/)